# LaTeX Beamer Template: Why aren't title and subititle/auther info aligned?

Tags: beamer

I am relatively new to creating my own beamer template and therefore my title page looks like a huge mess, mostly because the subtitlte and title are not left-aligned, as they should be. Similarly, my lines are far too close by each other, maybe because I include a title page image?

Here is the code and my result as an attached picture.

I am aware this is not a full MWE for the theme but for the slide/problem.

[image: the problematic title page]

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytheme}{%
  % list trick from http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=chngmargonfly
  \begin{list}{}{
  \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}}
  \item[]
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  {\usebeamerfont*{title}\color{adefinedcolor}\inserttitle\par} % no idea why usebeamercolor{title} does not work here

    \end{list}



\begin{columns}[T]

                \begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
                  \begin{block}
                      
         {\usebeamerfont*{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}           
       \vspace{\stretch{2}}
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{50pt}%
    {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par}
    {\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par}
    {\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par}
\end{block}
                \end{column}
                            \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
                     \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1pt,right]{mycolour}
        {\inserttitlegraphic}  
    \end{beamercolorbox}
                \end{column}
            \end{columns}
}
```

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace*{6mm}   \hfill \color{black!85}  \insertframenumber \hspace*{6mm}\vspace*{3pt}}




\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,natbib=true, url =false,isbn=false ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{pap-edge.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{orangeish}{RGB}{227,133,91}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}



\usepackage{comment}


\usetheme{mytheme}
\title{My really long title that goes on and on and on for serveral lines because it is such a long title that cannot be shortened please don't ask why} 
\subtitle{very short subtitle}
\author{Author A, Author B, Long-named Autor C}
%\institute{Naah don't need}
\date{\today}


\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{titleimage.png}}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{nonumberframe}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \begin{frame}[c,noframenumbering] %Remove the noframenumbering option if you want the counter to be increased on a frame that is not numbered.
    }{%
    \end{frame}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill \color{black!85}\insertframenumber \hspace*{6mm}\vspace*{3pt}}
}



\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}


\endocument
```

Comment: Can you pleas add a screenshot showing the titlepage produced to add relevant information? Thank you

Comment: oops so sorry yes I did!

Comment: No problem: happens to many of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Columns have different margins. You can use the same margins as for the surrounding text with the `onlytextwidth` option
- Using a list for the title seems awfully complicated
- Instead of `\usebeamercolor{title}`, you can use `\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}` to use the foreground colour of the title
- you don't need to load `xcolor` or `graphicx`, beamer already loads them for you

---

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace*{6mm}   \hfill \color{black!85}  \insertframenumber \hspace*{6mm}\vspace*{3pt}}




%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,natbib=true, url =false,isbn=false ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{pap-edge.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{orangeish}{RGB}{227,133,91}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}



\usepackage{comment}
\makeatletter

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytheme}{%
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  {\usebeamerfont*{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\par} 


\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]

                \begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
                  \begin{block}{}
                      
         {\usebeamerfont*{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}           
       \vspace{\stretch{2}}
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{50pt}%
    {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par}
    {\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par}
    {\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par}
\end{block}
                \end{column}
                            \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
                     \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1pt,right]{mycolour}
        {\inserttitlegraphic}  
    \end{beamercolorbox}
                \end{column}
            \end{columns}
}

\makeatother

\title{My really long title that goes on and on and on for serveral lines because it is such a long title that cannot be shortened please don't ask why} 
\subtitle{very short subtitle}
\author{Author A, Author B, Long-named Autor C}
%\institute{Naah don't need}
\date{\today}


\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{nonumberframe}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \begin{frame}[c,noframenumbering] %Remove the noframenumbering option if you want the counter to be increased on a frame that is not numbered.
    }{%
    \end{frame}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill \color{black!85}\insertframenumber \hspace*{6mm}\vspace*{3pt}}
}



\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is really helpul. For some reason (or rather because of the fonts my template forces me to use, see screenshot now attached) there is an awfully dense spacing in the left block between text liens. Is there any chance to make vertical spacing more "pleasantly"?

Comment: This will depend on your fonts for the subtitle, author etc. Please ask a new question with code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: okay, thanks, It's not that important - I'll accept your answer.